# long reply (50-60sec) from Prisma(Postgres) with NestJS if more then one repository

Tags: node.js, prisma

My schema:

```
generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
  output   = "../../../node_modules/.prisma/client"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "postgresql"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

enum UserRole {
  trainer
  client
}

model UserEntity {
  userId            Int                     @id @default(autoincrement()) @map("user_id")
  userName          String                  @default("") @map("user_name")
  userMail          String                  @unique @default("") @map("user_mail")
  userAvatar        String                  @default("") @map("user_avatar")
  passwordHash      String                  @default("")
  userGender        String                  @default("") @map("user_gender")
  birthDate         String                  @default("") @map("birth_date")
  userRole          UserRole                @map("user_role")
  description       String                  @default("")
  location          String                  @default("")
  backgraundPicture String                  @default("") @map("backgraund_picture")
  createdAt         DateTime                @default(now()) @map("created_at")
  clientBody        ClientBody?
  trainerBody       TrainerBody?
  levelOfExperience String                  @default("") @map("level_of_experience")

  @@map("users")
}

model ClientBody {
  clientBodyId          Int        @id @default(autoincrement()) @map("user_body_id")
  user                  UserEntity @relation(fields: [userId], references: [userId], onDelete: Cascade, onUpdate: Cascade)
  userId                Int        @unique @map("user_id")
  timeOfTraining        String     @default("") @map("time_of_training")
  caloryLosingPlanTotal Int        @default(0) @map("calory_losing_plan_total")
  caloryLosingPlanDaily Int        @default(0) @map("calory_losing_plan_daily")
  readinessForTraining  Boolean    @default(false) @map("readiness_for_training")

  @@map("client_body")
}

model TrainerBody {
  trainerBodyId       Int        @id @default(autoincrement()) @map("trainer_body_id")
  user                UserEntity @relation(fields: [userId], references: [userId], onDelete: Cascade, onUpdate: Cascade)
  userId              Int        @unique @map("user_id")
  sertificate         String     @default("")
  merit               String     @default("")
  readinessForPrivate Boolean    @default(false) @map("readiness_for_private")

  @@map("trainer_body")
}



model RefreshToken {
  refreshTokenId Int      @id @default(autoincrement()) @map("refresh_token_id")
  tokenId        String   @map("token_id")
  userId         String   @map("user_id")
  createdAt      DateTime @default(now()) @map("created_at")
  expiresIn      DateTime @default(now()) @map("expires_in")

  @@map("refresh_token_store")
}
```

Firstly this scheme has one repository for `UserEntity` and worked correct. When I made storage for `refreshToken` and repository\service for one situation not changed. But when I Injected  `RefreshTokenService` to `RefreshTokenService` and try to use method query increase a lot (up to 50 sec from 170ms before):

```
@Injectable()
export class FitnessUserService {
  constructor(
    private readonly fitnessUserRepository: RefreshTokenService,
    private readonly jwtService: JwtService,
    private readonly refreshTokenService: RefreshTokenService,
    @Inject(jwtConfig.KEY)
    private readonly jwtOptions: ConfigType<typeof jwtConfig>
  ) {}


  public async createUserToken(user: User) {
    console.log({ user });
    const accessTokenPayload = createJWTPayload(user);
    const refreshTokenPayload = {
      ...accessTokenPayload,
      tokenId: crypto.randomUUID(),
    };
    //if one here then delay increse form 120 ms up to 50000ms!!!!
    await this.refreshTokenService.createRefreshSession(refreshTokenPayload);

    return {
      accessToken: await this.jwtService.signAsync(accessTokenPayload),
      refreshToken: await this.jwtService.signAsync(refreshTokenPayload, {
        secret: this.jwtOptions.refreshTokenSecret,
        expiresIn: this.jwtOptions.refreshTokenExpiresIn,
      }),
    };
  }
}
```

in console with "npm run" received long log:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1KrBe.png)

I need this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cYofZ.png)change to this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Hn74.png)

Comment: If I understand correctly, adding the RefreshToken model increased the time duration for queries?

Comment: time duration increasing when  RefreshToken model using

Comment: sorry.. in repository was `console.log (this.prisma)`. it was reason of delay and long logs.